# Improvements in led indication with RTOS code

Tags: c, embedded, led, rtos, cmsis

I want to make certain effects with RGB led which changes colour using PWM signals.

```
|¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯||¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯||¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯|
|  Green   ||  Yellow  ||  Pink    |
|__________||__________||__________|
     15ms       10ms        25ms
|¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯||¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯||¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯|
|   Blue   ||  Magneta ||   Blue   |
|__________||__________||__________|
     20ms       10ms        20ms
```

Based on interrupt, these led colours should be displayed on LED.
I made a task specifically for this purpose and running these effects on that task.

```c
while(1)
{
    if (indication_type == event_a)
    {
        led_color_green();
        osDelay(15);
        led_color_yellow();
        osDelay(10);
        led_color_pink();
        osDelay(25);
    }
    else if (indication_type == event_b)
    {
        led_color_blue();
        osDelay(20);
        led_color_magneta();
        osDelay(10);
        led_color_blue();
        osDelay(20);
    }
    else
        ..
        ..
}
```

Code is working but there are two issues

1. Each led effect is visible for 50ms and if an event change has occurred, the led keeps on executing the previous state and a new state is showed after it has exited if-else condition with delay as per current implementation. How can I change the led indication immediately after receiving an interrupt?
2. I think there should be some clean way to make such effects especially with led. How can I improve this code? Any code reference you can share?

I am using STM32F4 and [CMSIS RTOS v2](https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/cmsis/RTOS2/html/index.html)

Comment: add curly braces for if/else blocks ...

Comment: Thanks @kraego, it was kind of pseudo code that I pasted here. Modified the same just in case.

Comment: You realize you are just calling `led_color_green` 3 times over yeah? And not switching colors.

Comment: Thanks @Lundin, fixed the same.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be able to make a decision about the "indication type" at every time quanta (tick), and switch the sequence immediately.

The following is an outline of one way to do that:

```
    // Color/time descriptor for each sequence
    static const struct 
    {
        void (*setcolor)(void) // Pointer to color set function
        int showtime ;         // Time to display color
        
    } indication_descriptor[][3] = 
    {
       { {led_color_green, 15}, {led_color_green, 15}, {led_color_green, 15} }, // event_a sequence
       { {led_color_blue, 15}, {led_color_magneta, 15}, {led_color_blue, 15} },  // event_b sequence
       ...
    } ;
    
    // Sequence control variables
    int last_indication_type = indication_type - 1 ; // force "change" on first iteration
    int current_indication = 0 ;
    int current_step = 0 ;
    int step_time = 0 ;
    
    while(1)
    {
        // On indication change...
        if( indication_type != last_indication_type )
        {
            // Set the indication descriptor...
            if( indication_type == event_a )
            {
                current_indication = 0 ;
            }
            else if( indication_type == event_b )
            {
                current_indication = 1 ;
            }
            ...
            
            last_indication_type = indication_type ;

            // Set initial indication color and time for this sequence
            current_step = 0
            step_time = indication_descriptor[current_indication][0].showtime ;
            indication_descriptor[current_indication][0].setcolor() ;
        }
        
        // Wait one tick
        osDelay(1) ;
        
        // Decrement time in step
        step_time-- ;
        
        // If end of step...
        if( step_time == 0 )
        {
            // Set colour and time for next step
            current_step == (current_step % 3) ;
            step_time = indication_descriptor[current_indication][current_step].showtime ;
            indication_descriptor[current_indication][current_step].setcolor() ;
        }
    }
```

It is likely that further improvements can be made, but from the fragment you have provided it is not possible to advise.  For example the data type and range of `indication_type`, `event_a` etc are not shown - it is possible that a `switch-case` or lookup table or even arithmetic could replace the `if/else if/.../else` selection block, but more information would be required.

If you need faster and more deterministic sequence interruption than 1ms you'd have to use an `osTimer`, with a callback function that sets a thread flag and have the task wait on a thread flag rather than `osDelay()`.  The interrupter can then set a different thread flag to wake the task to abort the timer and switch indication. That is somewhat more complex however and likely not necessary in this case.  A pattern that is useful for when hard-real-time response at the microsecond order is required.  If you did that the sequence code might change thus:

```
            ...
            
            // Set initial indication color and time for this sequence
            current_step = 0
            osTimerStart( step_timer, indication_descriptor[current_indication][0].showtime ) ;
            indication_descriptor[current_indication][0].setcolor() ;
        }
        
        // Wait for timer expiry or event
        uint32_t flags = osThreadFlagsWait( STEP_COMPLETE_FLAG | SEQUENCE_CHANGE_FLAG, osFlagsWaitAny, step_time ) ;
        
        // If end of step...
        if( (flag & STEP_COMPLETE_FLAG) != 0 )
        {
            // Set colour and time for next step
            current_step == (current_step % 3) ;
            step_time = indication_descriptor[current_indication][current_step ].showtime ;
            indication_descriptor[current_indication][current_step].setcolor() ;
        }
        else
        {
            osTimerStop( step_timer ) ;
        }
```

It has the advantage of having far fewer task context switches which may be useful if you need to reduce CPU load to achieve real-time deadlines or reduce power consumption by entering sleep for longer periods.

Comment: This explanation is much detailed and also emphasis is given on power consumption approach which I totally didn't think of. Thank you for making it quite clear and easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

`osWait` allows you to wait for either an event or a timeout. So if you can generate a proper signal when you have an interrupt, the thread will wake-up and you can immediately switch LED state.

See https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/cmsis/RTOS/html/group__CMSIS__RTOS__Wait.html#details

Comment: I went through the implementation and think I might end up  with code spaghetti as I have used `osDelay`(soon to experiment with `osWait`) too frequently.
Also I am using CMSIS RTOS v2 which I didn't mention earlier, will see if it is available in v2 and get back after testing `osWait`.

Comment: @Android_dev Another alternative is to use shorter delays so that you can check a flag more often... but `osWait` seemed a good solution

Comment: No `osWait` in V2.  You'd have to use an `osTimer`, with a call back function that set a thread flag and have the task wait on a thread flag rather then `osDelay()`.  The interrupter can then set a different thread flag to wake the task to abort the timer and switch indication.  That is somewhat more complex however and likely not worth the effort - a pattern that is useful for when hard-real-time response at the microsecond order is required.

Answer (score 0):

Put the RTOS to work and use an RTOS timer. From the interrupt that triggers the change in indication_type, you can call your function to set the color and then start the timer for the desired color duration (this can also be done in a task context after the interrupt notifies the task). On the timeout, set the next color and restart the timer with the next color duration. When indication_type changes, you can simply set the color again and restart the timer with the new indication_type color pattern.